# How to remote desktop to Azure App?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-api-apps

I have created an `Azure API App`. Then I need to run some command line for testing on that environment. In Azure classic I can do remote desktop to `Cloud services` to run some command line but now in `Azure App` it seems I am unable to do this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need to run something in the command line you can log in to the Kudu instance for your app (just go to http://*your_appname*.scm.azurewebsites.net in your browser) and open the `Debug Console`. You can choose between CMD and PowerShell.

Answer (score 5):

You can run basic commands even for Azure app Services. Just navigate to "Tools" in the essentials blade of your App service and then click on "console" link to navigate to the Command Prompt.

[image: Azure App Service - Console]

Thanks,
Prawin